# Laravel Socialite Google OAuth missing required paramater client_id

Tags: laravel, laravel-socialite

When I try to login with google using the Laravel Socialite package, it 
returns an error saying missing required paramater Client_ID. I have 
defined the id in my .env file and called it here in my services.php file. Not sure why this error is happening. Any assistance with this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

My services.php file:

```
'google' => [
    'client_id' => env('GOOGLE_ID'),
    'client_secret' => env('GOOGLE_SECRET'),
    'redirect' => env('GOOGLE_URL'),
],
```

My .env file:

```
GOOGLE_ID=xxxxxxxxxx
GOOGLE_SECRET=xxxxx
GOOGLE_URL=URL/login/google/callback
```

Comment: Try including a default client ID by changing `env('GOOGLE_ID')` to `env('GOOGLE_ID', 'invalid-id')` and then try again: does the error change? That will allow you to determine if the issue is with your `.env` or with your config.

Comment: When do you get it? On initial redirect after `return Socialite::with('google')->redirect();` ?